# Errors executing basic commands after installing python switch-model package

Tags: python-3.x, installation, conda

I'm trying to install switch-model 2.0 so I can play around with it:

https://switch-model.org/

I've tried installing it using conda and pip, which seems to succeed. But when I try to run basic commands in Anaconda Prompt I get an "unexpected token" type error (shown in the attached image).
Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

[pic of command and error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzLg6.png)

Answer (score 1):

I emailed Matthias Fripp (the man behind the switch model). He told me that there is an inbuilt command in anaconda prompt called "switch". That's where my error came from. So, all I had to do was change my commands from things like "switch --version" to "switch.exe --version" and I was in business.

Shoutout to Mr. Fripp, for his help, and check out this google group if you need help getting started with the switch-model:

https://groups.google.com/g/switch-model